# organizing multi-tenant db/MySQL [SaaS]

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, architecture

Good example will be shopify. Where you have N number of users (in this case each user assume site). And each user will have it's own records in DB. But db schema will be the same (same tables for each user, `products`, `customers`, `orders` etc.).

So question is what will be the best way to organize this kind of solution?
Store everything in one DB but in a different tables, or run separate DB for each user (but then will be question with maintaining, scalability and automatization)

### possible solution:

We can use one DB with common tables like `products`, `customers`, `orders` etc. And we will have table `users` where we store records about each site.
In tables `products`, `customers` we will group all records by `user_id`.
This is one of possible solutions. But if we will have 1000 users (sites), each will have ~2k products, and ~100k customers, we can end up with tables which has millions of records, so questions will be:

- how it will perform compare to each user (site) would have it's own DB?
- how reliable this approach? bigger data, harder maintain, backup/restore
- safety, if something wrong with one source thousands will be affected

Any links etc. will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reviewing databases by well-supported open source solutions. With this in mind, here's a pretty simple schema I found real quick that'd explain a good working solution for this with scale-ability in mind.

http://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-sample-database/

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a mysql user for each tenant
2. Add a tenant_id column to each table
3. Add a view for each table that filters based on tenant_id = mysql_user
4. Use a trigger to automatically populate the tenant_id column on INSERT
5. Restrict the tenant mysql users to only access the views, not the raw tables

I wrote up a blog post on how I was able to convert a large single-tenant mysql application to a multi-tenant application in a weekend using this technique.
https://opensource.io/it/mysql-multi-tenant/